# What exactly do the maven-jar-plugin Maven plugin? What is the difference using or not using this plugin?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, maven-jetty-plugin

I am working on a simple Spring console application (it is a batch having a class with the classic main() method()) and I have the following doubt about the **pom.xml** Maven file. This file only contains the required Spring dependencies needed to work. When I run the **Maven install** statment it generates the related **.jar** compiled application into the **target** directory of my project.

I was looking to another similar old project on which I worked in the past and into its **pom.xml** I can find this **maven-jar-plugin** plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.myCompany.main.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So what this **maven-jar-plugin** exactly does (also without using it the **maven install** statment generates a compiled **.jar** file). What is the difference using or not using this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar plugin allow us to define a default manifest file. With that option, the file located at ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF will be the manifest file in the jar
The maven jar plugin provides the capability to build jars files, if you define that your project is packaged as a jar file, maven will call implicitly to this plugin. We don´t need to define it inside pom.xml it will be downloaded and executed when maven needs it.So does not matter whether you use this inside your pom or not,it will get automatically loaded by maven if needed.

Refer this link for better undertanding
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/maven-jar-plugin-example/

Answer (score 0):

Maven Jar plugin is responsible for configuring where the project's main class is so it can add it to the Jar's manifest file. If you do not include this plugin when you try to run the jar file this error will appear :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

no matter if you have added this line somewhere else:

```
<mainClass>yourapp.Mainclass</mainClass>
```

the correct way is to add the above line in the maven-jar-plugin.